Agave status in devnet/ mainnet RPC
I am a bit confused... I get the agave fork is the new official validator for Solana.
Is this fully deployed? What about RPC provider like Helius, Anchor or the others.
Do everyone runs the Agave fork now?

Agave is a Solana validator client built by the Anza team. At the current time of writing, the majority of validators use Agave for their validators to run the Solana network.
You can find the full source code under Anza's github org plus more information in Anza's public blog.
